# Report Builder - Convert datetime to Local Time

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm using Report Builder 2.0 to construct a report that contains datetime data stored in the database as UTC time. Is there a way to convert the UTC time to local time of the computer viewing the report?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled upon the answer to my question. The Data Source View lets you specify whether a column holds local time or UTC time under the "DateTimeMode" property.

Comment: Can you write where this property is located? I am using Report Builder 3.0 and I can't find such.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull using DateTimeConversion.
Reports are shown by Client and computer by your Report Server.
The dates used by ToLocalTime Method and DateTimeMode are converted to Your Report Server local time which could be different from the browsing client computer.

Answer (score 0):

use this: [TimeZone..::.ToLocalTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.tolocaltime.aspx)

look here too: http://www.windows-tech.info/15/9115c76955a6a6e1.php

Comment: Wait.. It seems that this solution uses the time zone of the Report Server.. Not the time zone of the client viewing the report. :(

Comment: @James Jones, that is what the second link explains., that link also says that the only solution is to have the client pass in the desired time zone, so the report can generate based on that.  There is no other way (than client passing a parameter) for a report to be generated on a server, yet know the client's time zone.